# How do I capture the referrer from the root directory of the domain?

Tags: php, apache, referrer

The default document for my website is index.php. If people visit my website **www.MySite.com/** the referrer is empty when I look at it in my index.php file. If they visit **www.MySite.com/index.php**, the referrer is visible and I capture it with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. I know not every browser will forward the referrer.

How can I capture the referrer from the root directory if it exists?

Comment: you should use another headers

Comment: That won't do anything. By that time, the REFERER is over written. I need to access the REFERER when a user lands on the root.

Answer (score 0):

If the user entered the URL manually, or clicked a link from a favourite list in his browser, there is no referer. He literally came from nowhere :)

Comment: I know that. 

If I visit the site from a link like this: **www.MySite.com** I get no referer. If I visit from a link like this: **www.MySite.com/index.php** I get one.

I suspect the referer is being over written then a visitor lands in the root where my code doesn't get executed..